# Unable to get json body response from webhook laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I have been trying to get a json response body when webhook hit on my URL but failing. This is my controller method

```
public function sendSMS(Request $request){

        $response = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
        Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', Response::json($response));

   }
```

It always save a empty response in .txt. Can you help me out.

Answer (score 0):

there have lots of reasons you get errors here.
I suggest you try debug the following reasons:

1. dump(file_get_contents('php://input')) check if the post is valid json
2. make sure your file file.txt is writable
3. make sure Storage configuration is correct

Comment: I have tested the webhook on my own and it work but when I add this webhook in the site and try to test it didn't work.